# Modelsummary: DV names and Model Names at the same time in differen rows?

Tags: r, format, modelsummary

I was wondering how to use modelsummary to combine model names and DV names as in outreg2 in Stata? Here is the reprex:

```
    url <- 'https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/HistData/Guerry.csv'
dat <- read.csv(url)
models <- list(
  "OLS 1"     = lm(Donations ~ Literacy + Clergy, data = dat),
  "Poisson 1" = glm(Donations ~ Literacy + Commerce, family = poisson, data = dat),
  "OLS 2"     = lm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy + Clergy, data = dat),
  "Poisson 2" = glm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy + Commerce, family = poisson, data = dat),
  "OLS 3"     = lm(Crime_prop ~ Literacy + Clergy, data = dat)
)
modelsummary(models)

#N: DV names
modelsummary(dvnames(models), output = "flextable", estimate="{estimate}{stars}",
             statistic = 'statistic', stars = c('*' = .1, '**' = .05, '***'=0.01))
#N: Model names
modelsummary(models, output = "flextable", estimate="{estimate}{stars}",
             statistic = 'statistic', stars = c('*' = .1, '**' = .05, '***'=0.01))
```

Here is how a DV and model name combined table would look in `outreg2` in Stata:
[image]

Any info or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want to add a distinct row with dependent variables, you might want to use the `add_rows` argument: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#add-rows

Comment: Hi @Vincent, I looked at add_rows. Is there any way to dynamically extract the dep variables and build the rows tribble on the fly so that we don't have prespecify the terms in advacne? Is that the only way?

Comment: I'm using add_rows just to change the terms using the following adaptation of your code:
`library(tibble)
rows <- tribble(~term,          ~OLS,  ~Logit)
attr(rows, 'position') <- c(0)

modelsummary(models, add_rows = rows)`
But it throws an error:   Assertion on 'add_rows' failed: Must have at least 1 rows, but has 0 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [use the `add_rows` argument](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#add-rows) and create your own custom function to automate the process:

```r
library(modelsummary)

insert_row <- function(x) {
    out <- c("DV:", names(dvnames(x)))
    out <- data.frame(as.list(out))
    attr(out, "position") <- 0
    return(out)
}

mod <- list(
    lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars),
    lm(vs ~ hp, mtcars))

modelsummary(mod, add_rows = insert_row(mod))
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DV: | mpg | vs |
| (Intercept) | 30.099 | 1.217 |
|  | (1.634) | (0.150) |
| hp | -0.068 | -0.005 |
|  | (0.010) | (0.001) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 |
| R2 | 0.602 | 0.523 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.589 | 0.507 |
| AIC | 181.2 | 28.3 |
| BIC | 185.6 | 32.7 |
| Log.Lik. | -87.619 | -11.134 |
| F | 45.460 | 32.876 |

Comment: Works great and also gives some help on how to add features to the package! Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if I should open a new question, but is there a way to stipulate the row position programmatically? Say the last row of whatever size the table will be or the row before R2? Again, thank you for your answers - most helpful!

Comment: Yes. My code above shows how to set the "position". You will also find a description in the documentation of `add_rows` ( type `?modelsummary`) and on the website: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#add_rows

Comment: I went over that info several times and the only example is when position is a predetermined constant "attr(rows, 'position') <- c(3, 9)". Is there a way to make it dynamic? Sort of like "attr(rows, 'position') <- c(3, nrow(future_reg_coefficient_table))"? Whatever the number of rows in the resulting table that particular row would always be appended as the bottom row. An even better  approach could be just to specify "attr(rows, 'position') <- c(3, find(R2)-1)" where the row would be inserted right above a row with R2 in it.

Comment: Interesting idea, but it would be hard to implement. A workaround would be to generate the table twice. The first time you `output="data.frame"`, then you dynamically figure out where to insert it in the data frame, and you use that info to prep your `add_rows`. Not ideal, but shouldn't take more than 3-4 lines of code.